# Flutter Align TextFormField with DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have the following code that renders a `ListTile` with a `TextFormField` and a `ListTitle` with a `DropdownButton`.

```
           Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      dense: true,
                      title: Text(
                        "Property Name",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      subtitle: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Enter the property name'
                        ),
                      ),
                      isThreeLine: true,
                    )
                ),
                new Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      dense: true,
                      title: Text(
                        "Contact Name",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      subtitle: DropdownButton<int>(
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text(
                              "John Smith",
                            ),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                            value: 2,
                            child: Text(
                              "Jon Doe",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _value = value;
                          });
                        },
                        value: _value,
                        hint: Text(
                          "Select Contact Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      isThreeLine: true,
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

but it produces the following:

[image]

Is there a way to align the Contact Name's DropdownButton bottom line to the Property Name's ListTile? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try 
`Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Use DropdownButtonFormField**

As for me, I rather choose to **replace** `Dropdown` widget with `DropdownButtonFormField`

change this

```dart
child: ListTile(
  dense: true,
  title: Text(
    "Contact Name",
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
  subtitle: DropdownButton<int>( // change this
    items: [
      ...
```

into this

```dart
child: ListTile(
  dense: true,
  title: Text(
    "Contact Name",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
  subtitle: DropdownButtonFormField<int>( // into this
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
      labelText: 'Select Contact Name',
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),
    ),
    items: [
      ...
```

**2. Remove hint params**

secondly, as we move **'Select Contact name'** to `label Text` inside InputDecoration, we can remove these lines :

```dart
hint: Text(
  "Select Contact Name",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

**3. Comparison**

We can discover three options that we already have in image below.

1. at the first row, it is solution proposed by KeykoYume
2. at the second row, it is solution proposed by Abhilash Chandran
3. at the last row, it is **new solution** proposed by me

[image: Debug Painting enabled]
[image: Final result]
[image: Overflow handling]

Take note, that the third row also automatically handle overflows nicely

Comment: Good Solution @ejabu. Looks pretty clean and good to know about this widget.

Answer (score 0):

Padding your dropdown button with top inset could help as shown below.

```dart
subtitle: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 19.0),
  child: DropdownButton<int>(
    items: [
      DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: 1,
        child: Text(
          "John Smith",
        ),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: 2,
        child: Text(
          "Jon Doe",
        ),
      ),
    ],
    onChanged: (value) {
//                setState(() {
//                  _value = value;
//                });
    },
    value: 1,
    hint: Text(
      "Select Contact Name",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```